# If we deploy an application on AWS EC2 instance how do we enable AWS Single Sign On for that application ? Is that possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If we deploy a Javascript application on AWS EC2 instance how do we enable AWS Single Sign On for that application ? Is that possible ?

Description: I have an application deployed on Amazon EC2 Bitnami Instance and connected to Amazon RDS, can i connect the application to Amazon AWS Single Sign On? and if yes how do i do it ?

Answer (score 2):

IAM is only designed to securely control access to AWS services and resources in a back end manner, in other words, you can use IAM, which is AWS' single sign on service, for controlling access to the EC2 instance terminal but not to applications you install on top of EC2.

Comment: So is there a way in which we can enable Single Sign on for any application deployed on EC2 instance ? ( How to integrate AD with EC2 Instance Application ? )

Comment: Firstly you need to differentiate between federated authentication and single sign on. If you simply want users to be able to use the same username and password when the authenticate between applications then you can use Active Directory and set each application to authenticate against that LDAP source, if however you want your users to only have to enter their username and password once and have them automatically authenticated into each application from then on for the duration of the session then take a look at SAML.